# Output multi-dimensional array in a Two dimensionals table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, pdo

I'm desperately looking to create a small PHP-based inventory management system.

I have products (for this example, shoes), available in different shops, with different quantities between each shop.

I would like to display them in a HTML table according to the model below. It's a two headers table (left column is for displaying size, first row for shop name)

[image]

Here are my tables :

```
CREATE TABLE `shoes_ref` (
`id` smallint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -- Primary key with Auto_I
`model` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`color` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`picture` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`last_update` date DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `shoes_shop` (
`id` smallint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -- Primary key with Auto_I
`shop_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `shoes_stock` (
`id` smallint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -- Primary key with Auto_I
`id_ref` smallint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -- Foreign key on shoes_ref(id)
`id_shop` smallint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -- Foreign key on shoes_shop(id)
`size` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
`qty` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT shop_name, size, qty
FROM shoes_stock stock
LEFT JOIN shoes_ref ref ON ref.id = stock.id_ref
LEFT JOIN shoes_shop shop ON shop.id = stock.id_shop
WHERE ref.model = "Paris" AND ref.color = "Vegetal" -- here, I want available quantity for Paris Vegetal
ORDER BY size, qty
```

which allows me to get the following

[image]

but when it comes to formatting it with PHP, and sorting my array to get the same result as my example picture, I'm completely stuck.

Who would want to help me ? I'll be forever grateful to him . **I promise I'll give my next child the same name as my savior !!**

#### Edit

From the MySQL result, this is the result I want to get:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>F</th>
            <th>K</th>
            <th>S</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>6</strong><td>2</td><td>1</td><td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>7</strong><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>8</strong><td>0</td><td>3</td><td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>9</strong><td>0</td><td>1</td><td>0</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Create static html-markup that is the same as you required, then apply it to your data received from SQL query.

Comment: @u_mulder, if only it were that easy  the problem is that the horizontal header of the table (with shop name) is dynamic and depends of the availability of the shoes in the store

Comment: Maybe you will need to sort on Shop Name first if you want that to be the main heading,  and remove Qty completly

Comment: why should I remove qty ? it's the most important information I need.

Comment: Please give your Example (what I want) model sensible column names and a bit of sensible data, make it a bit easier for us to follow

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've edited my post friend

Comment: So what are `F` and `K` and `S`

Comment: these are the shop names (their initials to be precise)

Comment: Ahhhhhh finally the penny dropped. I can be a bit of a dipstick sometimes

Comment: Please don't underestimate yourself. I'm sure once you get going, there's no stopping you.

Comment: How did you plan to store a size of `6 1/2` in a column defined as `tinyint(1)` or come to that a realistic qty in another `tinyint(1)`

Comment: yes, you are right mate. I should change the type of the column